# Validation on associtions in rails with roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, roles

So I have two ActiveRecord classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buyer_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => :buyer_id
  has_many :seller_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => :seller_id

  validates_presence_of :name # THIS SHOULD ONLY BE RUN IF USER IS A SELLER
                              # IN THE DEAL
  validates_presence_of :phone # THIS SHOULD ONLY BE RUN IF USER IS A BUYER
                              # IN THE DEAL
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User'

  validates_associated :seller
  validates_associated :buyer
end
```

What I want to do is create a new deal with.

```
Deal.create(A NICE STRUCT WITH SELLER AND BUYER)
```

However I only want to run the name validation if the relation from the deal is a seller and the phone if the the relation from the deal is a seller, is this possible in rails, does not seem to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by [adding a condition to you validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).

So, your `User` class would wind up looking something like...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buyer_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => :buyer_id
  has_many :seller_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => :seller_id

  validates_presence_of :name, :if => :has_an_active_seller_deal?
  validates_presence_of :phone, :if => :has_an_active_buyer_deal?

  def has_active_seller_deals?
    seller_deals.count > 0
  end

  def has_active_buyer_deals?
    buyer_deals.count > 0
  end
end
```

An alternative to this would be to simply require all users to have a name and phone number on file at all times (no conditional validation), and only reveal it to other users with which they had active deals, and not as part of a user's public profile, thereby protecting the user's privacy when possible. This would probably be simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You could put the validations in a callback:

```
before_save :check_user_type

private
def check_user_type
  user_type = self.responds_to?(seller_id) ? :seller : :buyer
  if user_type == :seller
    validates_presence_of :name 
  else 
    validates_presence_of :phone
  end
```